# Why do some apps appear in the Software Center Installed apps and some do not?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, software-center

I have Ubuntu 16.04.  Some applications appear in the software center (like gparted or GIMP.  Some applications like Google Earth do not.  What determines when an application appears in the Software Center?  If applications do not appear in the Software Center how do you know they are installed?  How do you find the correct text so that you can uninstall something not in the software center using  `sudo apt-get remove`?

Comment: Gnome Software (which replaced Ubuntu Software Centre some time ago) uses a database of software, so only shows programs/apps that are listed in it's database.  Software Boutique and other alternatives also use databases (but different ones so can have different selections; ie. i'd expect google-earth to show in the boutique but not in gnome-software). Both can list snaps as well as packages (snaps would be removed with `sudo snap remove`); or you can use package managers that show everything in your software lists (like aptitude/synaptic/.., but will ignore snaps)